# Create a TryMapOrReturnDefault pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I am currently trying to work out a 'TryMapOrReturnDefault' pattern, I already have a map method which throws an exception in case it fails, but I need in some cases to have it return something (either user specified or null by default)

but how I do actually do it,

It seem wrong to "just" wrap the map method in a try finally, and in case an exception is being triggered return default value or am I wrong here - seem like I am misusing the fact an exception is being triggered, or is that the way to do it?

```
public static CustomModel? TryMapOrDefault(FieldType value, string title, CustomModel? defaultValue = null)
{
    CustomModel? returnValue = defaultValue;
    try
    {
        returnValue = Map(value, title);
    }
    finally
    {

    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: `if (CanMap(value, title)) { return Map(value, title); } else { return defaultValue; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seem wrong to "just" wrap the map method in a try finally, and in
> case an exception is being triggered return default value or am I
> wrong here - seem like I am misusing the fact an exception is being
> triggered, or is that the way to do it

In my view, you can use `try-catch` statement because you have plan B when your program meet an exception.
So, it is perfectly eligible to me to use `try-catch` statement here because you can return `default` value and this is plan b.

It is not the case when an error is unrecoverable. E.g., you cannot read data from table because table was dropped recently from database. On the other hand, if error can be recovered, then you can go with `try-catch`

### UPDATE:

If `Map` function does not throw exception, then it is possible to check `null` and then just return default value:

```
public static CustomModel? TryMapOrDefault(FieldType value, string title, 
    CustomModel? defaultValue = null)
{
    CustomModel? returnValue = defaultValue;
    
    returnValue = Map(value, title);

    if (returnValue is null) 
        returnValue = defaultValue; 

    return returnValue;
}
```

If you want to return `defaultValue` when `Exception` is thrown, then you can use `catch` statement to assign default value.

Let me show an example:

```
public static CustomModel? TryMapOrDefault(FieldType value, string title, 
    CustomModel? defaultValue = null)
{
    CustomModel? returnValue = defaultValue;
    try
    {
        returnValue = Map(value, title);
    }
    catch (Exception ) {
        returnValue = defaultValue; 
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: The question lies in whether it is correct to rely on triggering an exception to find out whether you able to map or not - is it correct to trigger an exception on purpose to return a default value - or should one have evaluated the input parameter with if statements to then return default value?

Comment: @IamnotFat does your `Map` function throws exception? Please, see my updated answer

Comment: Yes, it throws an exception in case it fails. 
It evaluated whether the input params are null and throws nullexception

Comment: @IamnotFat *should one have evaluated the input parameter with if statements to then return default value*, I think, you can create a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> for that case, but I would prefer `try catch` statement

Comment: Using exceptions for control flow is considered as an anti-pattern.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: @IamnotFat I think, it is very debatable theme. It depends on many factors, e.g. when it is used, what it is going after exception handling. I am trying to stick with this point [Why not use exceptions as regular flow of control?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729411)